# Make 3rd column in Magento Footer (category list)

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have a list of sub-categories displayed in my footer.  Currently the list is in 2 columns, but I would like it to be in 3 columns.

Here is the code I currently have working;

```
<li class='shop_online'>        
    <?php
            #########################################
            $temparray = array();
            $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
            $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
            $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if (count($_categories) > 0): 
                foreach($_categories as $_category):

                        $temparray[] = "<a href='".$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category)."'>".$_category->getName()."</a>";
                    /*
                        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
                        $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
                    if (count($_subcategories) > 0):

                        foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory):
                                $temparray[] = "<a href='".$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory)."'>".$_subcategory->getName()."</a>";

                                $_subsubcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId());
                                $_subsubcategories = $_subsubcategory->getChildrenCategories();
                                if (count($_subsubcategories) > 0):

                                    foreach($_subsubcategories as $_subsubcategory):        
                                        $temparray[] = "<a href='".$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subsubcategory)."'>".$_subsubcategory->getName()."</a>";                                        
                                    endforeach;                                  
                                endif;                               
                        endforeach;                          
                    endif; 
                  */
                endforeach;

            endif;

    echo "<ul class='footer_links_list'>";
            if(count($temparray) > 0)
            {
                echo '<h3><a href="'.Mage::getBaseUrl().'shop-online'.'">SHOP ONLINE</a></h3>';
                for( $i=0; $i<count($temparray); $i++ )
                {
                    if(($i+1)%1==0 || ($i+1)%1==0)
                    echo "<li>".$temparray[$i]."</li>";
                }
            }
    echo "</ul>";
            #########################################
            ?>
  </li>
```

I cannot figure out how to break this into a 3rd column for display in the footer.

formagdev1.com is the dev site I am working on.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the width of the below class to 33% (original 50%) in styles.css at line 1808 and you should be good to go.

`ul.footer_links_list li`

Cheers!

Comment: Heh, I thought about trying that but then thought, why would it be so simple?!?!  Either way, thanks very much!

Comment: Most of the problems in this world are simple, we just see it in a complicated way :) Anyway, you have got very nice website design.